# 100% CPU utilization in either gettimeofday, QTime or QLabel->setText

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I've been working on a simple dialog widget that should display GMT time at a rate of 10 Hz. Since the system I'm working on runs for days and days, it should be stable.

On some overnight runs, I've noticed that my "BAR" program is running at 100 % after several hours of execution. I'm flummoxed as to why this occurs, but I've been able to narrow it down to three functions:

I'm using a simple function called `ace_time` to obtain time of day:

```
inline double ace_time(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timezone tz;
    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    return (double) tv.tv_sec + 1e-6 * (double) tv.tv_usec;
}
```

And then I obtain the milliseconds, seconds, minutes, etc, from the return of this function. I then use `QTime` to format it:

```
QTime time(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
QString timeStr = time.toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
```

And then set the text in my label:

```
clock->setText(timeStr);
```

I'm confused why I would get 100 % cpu usage, unless `gettimeofday`, `QTime` or `setText` are doing things that I'm not expecting.

Have the experts here noticed any of these functions behaving strangely?

I'm using Qt 4.8, if that helps.

Looking forward to getting some ideas to solve this. Thanks!

---

Adding more code:

I want to have two bars. A top and a bottom bar. So I've written a `BarBase` class and a `TopBar` class. I also needed to write a custom `QLayout` to help me with the layout. I highly doubt the layout manager is causing this because it is only called when the bar is resizing and the geometry needs to be recalculated.

```
class BarBase : public QWidget
{
public:
    BarBase()
    {
        setFixedHeight(barHeight);
        setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);                        

        QPalette palette;
        QColor color(50, 252, 50);
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Background, color);
        setAutoFillBackground(true);
        setPalette(palette);
    }
    virtual ~BarBase();

protected:
    QLabel *createWestLabel(const QString &);
    QLabel *createCenterLabel(const QString &);
    QLabel *createEastLabel(const QString &);

private:
    QLabel *createLabel(const QString &, Qt::Alignment)
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(str);
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | alignment);
        //label->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Raised);
        QFont font("Times");
        font.setPixelSize(barHeight - 4);
        font.setBold(true);
        label->setFont(font);
        return label;
     }
 };
```

And here is my class for the `TopBar` only

```
class TopBar : public BarBase
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TopBar()
    {
        Layout *layout = new Layout;

        classification = createCenterLabel("Classification");
        layout->addWidget(classification, Layout::Center);

        hostname = createWestLabel("Hostname");
        layout->addWidget(hostname, Layout::West);     

        layout->addWidget(createWestLabel(":"), Layout::West);
        software = createWestLabel("Software");
        layout->addWidget(software, Layout::West);

        runMode = createEastLabel("SIM");
        layout->addWidget(runMode, Layout::East);

        layout->addWidget(createEastLabel(":"), Layout::East);

        clock = createClockLabel("-dd::hh::mm::ss.z");
        layout->addWidget(clock, Layout::East);

        deadman = new QTimer;
        connect(deadman, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateLocalGMT()));
        deadman->start(100); // 10 ms;

        setLayout(layout);

        setWindowTitle(tr("Top Bar"));
    }

    virtual ~TopBar();

public slots:
    void updateLocalGMT()
    {
        double milliseconds = fmod(ace_time(), 86400.0) * 1000;

        bool sign = (milliseconds >= 0.0);

        if (!sign)
        {
            milliseconds = -milliseconds;
        }

        const int millisecondsToDays = 86400.0 * 1000.0;
        const int millisecondsToHours = 3600.0 * 1000.0;
        const int millisecondsToMinutes = 60 * 1000.0;
        const int millisecondsToSeconds = 1000.0;

        double days = floor(milliseconds / millisecondsToDays);
        milliseconds -= days * millisecondsToDays;

        double hours = floor(milliseconds / millisecondsToHours);
        milliseconds -= hours * millisecondsToHours;

        double minutes = floor(milliseconds / millisecondsToMinutes);
        milliseconds -= minutes * millisecondsToMinutes;

        double seconds = floor(milliseconds / millisecondsToSeconds);
        milliseconds -= seconds * millisecondsToSeconds;

        QTime time(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
        /*
        if (!time.isValid())
        {
            INFO("Invalid input to QTime [day, hour, min, sec, ms]: [%f %f %f %f %f]",
            days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
        }
        */

        QString timeStr = time.toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");
        timeStr = timeStr.left(timeStr.length() - 2); // to remove the last two z
        timeStr.prepend((sign) ? "+" : "-");
        timeStr.prepend("<code style='color:white'>");
        timeStr.append("</code>");

        // timeStr = timeStr.left(timeStr.length() - 2);

        // qDebug() << currentTime;
        clock->setText(timeStr);
    }

private:
    QLabel *classification;
    QLabel *hostname;
    QLabel *software;
    QLabel *runMode;
    QLabel *clock;

    QLabel *createClockLabel(const QString &text)
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(text);
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
        QFont font("Monospace");
        font.setStyleHint(QFont::TypeWriter);
        font.setFixedPitch(true); // enforces monospace
        font.setPointSize(18);
        font.setBold(true);
        label->setFont(font);
        int pixelWidth = label->fontMetrics().width(label->text());
        label->setFixedWidth(pixelWidth);
        return label;
    }

    QTimer *deadman;
};
```

Comment: Are you perhaps doing this in a loop?

Comment: I don't think so. I have a `qTimer` doing a 100 ms timeout, and I connected the signal to the slot that uses these functions.

Comment: Seems rather unlikely that any of these functions would use 0.1s. I suspect you have a bug somewhere in the code you haven't posted...

Comment: That code seems fine, need more code... A note: you can pass `NULL` as timezone, if you do not need the value.

Comment: Another note: unless that `ace_time` is in a header file and you use `inline` to suppress linking error, then `inline` does not do what you think it does...

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why don't you use QTime's facilities to obtain the current time? It would make life easier.

Comment: idea to solve this: Remove code by commenting it out, until you see the problem disappear...

Comment: @hyde: I know how inline functions work. I have commented out all the code to get the smallest reproducible yet functional example.

Comment: @ypnos Chief engineer likes ace_time(), let me try using QTime to get GMT ans see if that fixes it.

Comment: `deadman = new QTimer;` canonical use is to add the this pointer to the constructor so deletion can happen automatically

Comment: @ratchetfreak Like this: `deadman = new QTimer(this)'`?

Comment: What happens if you at the startup call `updateLocalGMT()` function in a loop for example 360000 times (10 hours at 10 Hz) and then continue as usual? Is the CPU usage immediately high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QTimer can fall behind and queue up many notifications if your thread is busy - this will cause your processing to happen far more than you expect.

To workaround this you should do something like:

```
 void timer_slot()
 {
  if diff(now - last_time) < timer_interval
      return; // Timer has come in too early so don't do anything

  last_time = now;
 }
```

If you want to reproduce this just block your thread with a sleep() and you'll notice that the timer slot will be called for as many times as it should have been called while the thread was blocked.

The QTimer docs state that:

"Accuracy and Timer Resolution
Timers will never time out earlier than the specified timeout value and they are not guaranteed to time out at the exact value specified. In many situations, they may time out late by a period of time that depends on the accuracy of the system timers.
The accuracy of timers depends on the underlying operating system and hardware. Most platforms support a resolution of 1 millisecond, though the accuracy of the timer will not equal this resolution in many real-world situations.
If Qt is unable to deliver the requested number of timer clicks, it will silently discard some."

But I've found this not to be true on Windows 7 x64 if the thread is blocked/busy.

Comment: Are you *sure* timer events get queued? I'm almost 100% certain they do not. That is, the timer fill fire as often as it can, not "as often as it should have been called". If true, seems like a bug...

Comment: Yup last time I checked it used a thread and a queued connection to the slot.

Comment: Ah! Well, queued signals get queued. So the timer in one thread could easily run at requested interval and keep emitting signals, that is a very light operation after all, especailly if signal gets queued. Then the other thread kept unqueuing the signals as fast as it could, but there's no throttling mechanism with inter-thread signals. If the slot and the timer would have been in the same thread, even queued, then the slot would have blocked the timer and worked as docs say. So, "don't do that", and "threading is hard" ;)

Comment: So to be clear, this has nothing to do with QTimer specifically. `for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) { emit someSignalWithQueuedConnection(); }` will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I fixed this by overloading the repaint event and allowing the process queue to service it. You were right, however, I think that the timeout slot was being queued and would eventually lead to the 100% CPU usage. I'm accepting this answer because it pointed me in the correct direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "allowing the process queue to service it" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
deadman->start(10); // 10 ms;
```

(Note: answer written before question was fixed to have 100 ms interval)

You have 10ms interval here, which is 100Hz, not 10Hz. In your question you say "the system I'm working on runs for days and days", so it sounds like you have an embedded system of some sort? Maybe it has trouble keeping up with 100Hz timer.

Note that updating the label 100 times a second will cause [`QWidget::update()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update) to be called that often, and the widget will be painted from event loop very often, even if you do not call `repaint()` (which you should not do anyway).

Comment: That's something I was trying out in my debug code. I wanted to see if I could make it fail faster my making it 100 Hz. 100Hz is not production code, 10 Hz is.

Comment: I agree, I'm sure I saw somewhere on Qt website about how the timer thread could fall behind and fire constantly, this would cause the app to appear hung on the constant redrawing.

Comment: Even at 10Hz the update thread can fall behind? Do you have a link for that? That's curious.

Comment: I've posted an answer, this happens due to your thread actually doing other work or CPU time being starved by some other system process

Comment: @TylerJandreau If it is an embedded system with less than optimal display drivers and low-MHz CPU, then I could see updating the screen at 10 Hz could increase load a lot. Just try reducing the frequency to 1 Hz and see if it helps...